# Protecting Routes With Two middle-wares So that both users can access it

Tags: laravel

I am trying to protect a route using two middle-wares so that both expert and user can access the same route but as soon a user tries to access the route he is logged out.

I had created two middle-wares for expert and user and protect the route using these middle-wares.

Web.php

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => ['expert','user']], function () {
                Route::post('/showForm','UserController@showFormFilled');
        });
```

User Middle ware

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        //////////////////// check if user is logged in  ///////////////////
        if(Auth::check())
        {
            ////////////////// check user role id  //////////////////////////
            if(auth()->user()->role_id == 3)
            {
                return $next($request);
            }
            else if (auth()->user()->role_id==2)
            {
                return redirect('/expert');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return redirect('/login');
        }

    }
```

Expert Middle ware

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::check()){
            if(auth()->user()->role_id == 2)
                return $next($request);
            else if (auth()->user()->role_id==3)
                return redirect('/dashboard');
        }
        else {
            return redirect('/login');
        }
    }
```

Both the users should be able to access the same route.

Comment: add your user and expert middleware code also

Comment: What about `__construct` function in your `MainController`?

Comment: I have not added a `__construct` function in `MainController`

Comment: Could you verify if there are any additional requests being made when a user tries to access the above route? Looking the flow, when a user tries to login, the Expert middleware just redirects him to `/dashboard`, which would cause the same middleware to run again and never actually load the `/dashboard`?

Comment: **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS** 
this is the error I am seeing now when I try to access the above route

Comment: You are accessing `user` by `expert` or `user` middle-ware and at the same moment your are ignoring them. You have to improve your middle-ware condition.

Comment: Please have a look - https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/middleware-results-to-err-too-many-redirects

Comment: @hamzahummam - that's what I expected :-) Looks like you don't need the `expert` middleware on the `/dashboard` route anyway - since it just redirects users to their own dashboard.

Comment: @gvk yep :-) your right , let me update the question .......

Comment: Why not just use `auth` middleware together with your custom middlewares instead of explicitly checking if someone is logged in on both custom middlewares?

Comment: @gvk please have a look at the routes now , when I try to access this route `/showForm` as user it redirects me to the  `/dashboard`

Comment: @rkg it does solve my problem but we have 3 types of user Expert,User and Admin I dont want admin to access this route ...... I mean I only want Expert and User to access this route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@hamzahummam - there is no way to achieve what you are looking for using the above separate-middlware-for-each-type method. Each middleware prematurely redirects [either to `/dashboard` or to `/expert` etc] the request without allowing it to passthrough other middleware. Best would be to use a third-party package that provides a more comprehensive and fine-grained access control [example: https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust]

If that's not an option, the best case would be to implement a single middleware and pass the role as parameter. See: [Laravel Middleware Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware#middleware-parameters)

A minimal example would look like:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
{
    // Assuming Auth::check() passes
    $roleId = auth()->user()->role_id;

    if ($roleId == 2 && strpos($role, 'expert') !== false) {
        // Logged in user is `expert` and route allows `expert` access
        return $next($request);
    } else if ($roleId == 3 && strpos($role, 'user') !== false) {
        // Logged in user is `user` and route allows `user` access
        return $next($request);
    } // and so on...

    // Handle failures here
    if ($roleId == 2 && strpos($role, 'expert') === false) {
       // an `expert` is trying to access route that can't be accessed
       return redirect('/expert-dashboard');
    } // and so on...
}
```

You'd define routes as:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['new_middleware:expert,user' ]], function () {
    Route::post('/showForm','UserController@showFormFilled');
});
```

Hope this helps.